# How to apply server side validation on List of Object in spring boot? spring not validating List<Address> which is present in Employee Class

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data

I want to  validate List of Address and all its properties city, state , pincode
I have given all spring validation in Address class still its not validating.

Address Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")

public class Address {


@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "ADDR_ID")
private Long addr_id;

@NotNull(message="city should not be null")
@Column(name = "CITY")
private String city;

@NotNull(message="state should not be null")
@Column(name = "STATE")
private String state;

@NotNull(message="pincode should not be null")
@Column(name = "PINCODE")
private Integer pincode;


@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "FK_EMP_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
@JsonBackReference
@Valid
@NotNull
private Employee emp;

//getter & setter omitted for breveity
```

Employee Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;

@NotNull(message="name should not be null")
@Size(min=1,  max=15 ,message="Name should be min 1 and max 15")
@Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_NAME")
private String name;

@NotNull(message="salary should not be null")
@Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_SALARY")
private Integer salary;

@NotNull(message="department should not be null")
@Column(name = "DEPARTMENT")
private String department;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="emp", cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, 
orphanRemoval=true,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonManagedReference
@NotNull(message="address should contain atleast 1 address")
private List<Address> address = new ArrayList<Address>();

//getter & setter omitted for breveity
```

PostMan Json

```
{
"name": "aakash",
"salary": 546,
"department": "IT",
"age":32,
"email":"agag@gma",
"address":[
     {
        "city":"Mumbai"
     }
    ]

}
```

> When i pass list of address and some of its properties it's showing following 
>     error.

```
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes 
[com.example.springDataJPA.model.Address] during persist time for groups 
[javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='pincode should not be null', 
propertyPath=pincode, rootBeanClass=class 
com.example.springDataJPA.model.Address, messageTemplate='pincode should not 
be null'}
ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='state should not be null', 
propertyPath=state, rootBeanClass=class 
com.example.springDataJPA.model.Address, messageTemplate='state should not 
be null'}
```

I want to validate the list of address with all properties and should and it should return proper default message in json format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@NotNull checks only if the list is not null. Try to use @NotEmpty instead.

(The good article about the difference: https://www.baeldung.com/java-bean-validation-not-null-empty-blank)

Comment: It's is not validating for address properties

Comment: It's the separate problem. Add @ Valid onto List<String> addresses (like you did with private Employee emp), or onto generic (List<@Valid String> addresses), the latter is preferred according to Hibernate validator docs (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#_cascaded_validation, I suppose that you use that validation provider)